# how to make Numbering rows in a query

Tags: sql, row-number

I have a simple select statement:
Get numbering of rows from Product table in the following order: a name of the manufacturer in
--decreasing order of quantity of models produced by it (when there is identical quantity of models
--for a number of manufacturers, their names should follow in increasing alphabetic order), model (increasing order).
--Output: number in accordance with the above order, a name of the manufacturer (maker), model

RESULT SHOULD BE -

```
no  maker   model
1   A   1232
10  E   2112
11  E   2113
12  B   1121
13  B   1750
14  D   1288
15  D   1433
16  C   1321
2   A   1233
3   A   1276
4   A   1298
5   A   1401
6   A   1408
7   A   1752
8   E   1260
9   E   1434
```

MY QUERY :

```
with result as
(select *, count(*) over (partition by maker) as ModelsCount from Product)   
select row_number() over (order by ModelsCount desc,model) AS No, Maker, Model
from result
```

MY RESULT:

```
no  maker   model
1   A   1232
10  E   2112
11  E   2113
12  B   1121
13  D   1288
14  D   1433
15  B   1750
16  C   1321
2   A   1233
3   A   1276
4   A   1298
5   A   1401
6   A   1408
7   A   1752
8   E   1260
9   E   1434
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Depending on the database there multiple solutions.

Comment: Try `(order by ModelsCount desc, maker, model)`

Comment: database "Computer firm":
http://www.sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_1

Comment: thanks for your help. the solution is : with result as
(select *, count(*) over (partition by maker) as ModelsCount from Product)   
select row_number() over (order by ModelsCount desc, maker, model) AS No, Maker, Model
from result